# Step in proof about maximum of the solution of the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, heat-equation

I have to give a direct proof that if $U$ is bounded and $u ∈ C^2_1(U_T)∩C(\overline{U_T})$ solves the heat equation, then $$\max_{\overline{U_T}} u = \max_{Γ_T}u,$$ where $U_T := U ×(0,T]$ and $Γ_T := \overline{U_T} × \{0\} ∪(∂U ×[0,T])$.
In the proof they claim: if $∆u−u_t ≥ 0$ then $$\max_{\overline{U_T}} u = \max_{Γ_T}u.$$

I'm not sure why is that enough to show.

Comment: If something holds when $A \ge 0$, (greater than OR equal to 0) then it also holds when $A=0$.

Comment: @LucTuc Can you tell the name of book, you are following.

Comment: Lawrence C. Evans-Partial Differential Equations

Comment: @LucTuc have I solved your concerns....or do I not understand your problem?

Comment: @CalvinKhor yes thank you.